# Javascript Changing a time the server gives me to match another timezone

Tags: javascript

I have a web page, which has a table, of the columns in the table is Time something is changed. The time is taken from another page/server. I need to convert this time to UTC time so that i can add two hours to it and then get it displayed.

I have tried all methods online but nothing seems to work, any help guys?

Comment: What is the format of this time on the page? Have you access to handle this on server side?

Comment: this is the format: $("#date-"+tidm).text(data.lastTrade.date);       it is accessed from a link. nope i cant access any of the server side.

Comment: I meant: What is the format of the date being received (in `data.lastTrade.date`)?

Comment: Nope. What is the output of `alert(data.lastTrade.date);`?

Comment: The output would be: 12:04:04

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://momentjs.com/.

> A lightweight (4.3k) javascript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

```
alert(moment("2011-10-31", "YYYY-MM-DD").subtract('hours', 3));
```

**Edit:**
For your case:

```
var myTime = moment(data.lastTrade.date, "HH:MM:SS");
alert(myTime.utc().format("HH:MM:SS"));
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried that but it didn't work.. :( Would i need to use event.timeStamp?

Comment: Please, post your code in the question, so I can take a look.

Comment: If my solution doesn't solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer and accept it. This way you can help others with the same problems.